# Метод объекта в контексте другой функции

Tags: javascript

Мне интересно, почему ниже приведенный код возвращает undefined вместо 5:

```
var f = function() {
    this.x = 5;
    (function() {
        this.x = 3;
    })();
    console.log(this.x);
};

var obj = {x: 4, m: function() {
    console.log(this.x);
}};

obj.m.call(f);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почувствуйте разницу между

```
obj.m.call(f);
```

и

```
obj.m.call(new f);
```

В первом случае вы передаете функцию, а во втором - объект.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. То есть, функция в контексте другой функции не может быть вызвана? Но функция же в js - это объект...

Comment: @andreyqin ну погодите. Всё намного проще. Грубо говоря, когда вы создаете объект с помощью new, то с помощью call вы передаете объект вместе со всеми "кишками" :). А в вашем случае вы передаете только функцию, т.е. `this` в `obj.m` будет содержать функцию, которую можно будет вызвать так: `this()`. И т.к. это функция, а не объект, то значение `this.x` измениться только в передаваемой функции `f()`.

Вот, наверно как-то так.